# Запись разговора собеседника

Tags: android-sdk, android, звукозапись

Я записываю телефонный разговор при помощи AudioRecorder, но он записывает только тот звук, который поступает через микрофон, голоса самого собеседника не слышно. Как перехватить голос поступающий сигнал? Если есть API для определенных процессоров, то дайте, пожалуйста, ссылку.

Comment: у вашего recorder-a AudioSource.MIC стоит?